# SQL grammar for INSERT SELECT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to GROUP and aggregate the rows from one table and insert into the other, and update the aggregate value. What is the SQL command for that?

```
INSERT INTO tbdetail (detail, views)
(SELECT detail, SUM(views) AS viewsall
 FROM tb
 GROUP BY detail)
//ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + viewsall <- how to update here?
```

Comment: FYI, this is often referred to as an *upsert*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, when using an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, you can refer to one of the values of the `SELECT` statement using the `VALUES()` function:

```
INSERT INTO tbdetail (detail, views)

SELECT detail, SUM(views) AS viewsall FROM tb GROUP BY detail

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + VALUES(views);
```

More information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: Unknown column 'viewsall' in 'field list'

Comment: Ah! I'd *just* caught that... The parameter in `VALUES()` should match the `INSERT` field name, not the `SELECT` field name. Apologies! /fixed